# Is it possible to map a superclass and subclass by OneToOne relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, mapping, one-to-one

Is it possible to map a subclass to its superclass by OneToOne relationship base on their primary key properties in Hibernate? How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the JOINED inheritance strategy like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Cat implements Serializable {

  private int id;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public int getId() { 
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

@Entity 
public class DomesticCat extends Cat {

  private String name;

  public String getName() { 
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

This way, the id will be both in the `cat` and the `domesticcat` table, both as a primary key, and with a foreign key between the two. This gives you a one to one relationship (without using @OneToOne).

Comment: Is it possible to avoid join with each sub-class during query of parent type?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) in the Hibernate reference to understand inheritance mapping.